# Add an image in ComponentOne C1DataGrid column

Tags: wpf, templates, datagrid, wpf-controls, componentone

How to add an image in one grid column based on a condition (image will change depends on data in the grid column) in c1datagrid

I'm using autogenerate columns, biding grid with c1.data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it in one of the C1 demo project.

Comment: Can you please tell me what did you do ?!! I have the same problem